# IntelliJ Idea Scala files not available in 'New' context menu

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am new to both IntelliJ and Scala. I am attending the course *"Functional Programming Principles in Scala"* on Coursera. I downloaded the zip file for the sample assignment, which contained a sample Scala project.

I imported the project successfully (I guess) in IntelliJ. However, when I right-click on a package in the project explorer, there are no Scala-related templates. I can only select "New Java class", XML files and some forms.

Does anyone know why this happens and if there is another way to create a new Scala class or object from a template?

Thanks.

Comment: Yesterday this course started again, and the problem still exists :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Import the project by selecting its `build.sbt` file - not the project folder, not the eclipse project file. Then everything is imported correctly.

Answer (score 9):

For me it works as following:

Right clicked on src and selected "mark directory as" -> source root.

Comment: This worked for me. Only instead of 'src' I had to click on 'scala'.

Comment: Worked for me as well (IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.4). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This may also be a caching issue.
If so, try `File` then `Invalidate Caches / Restart`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to make the scala directory a *source* directory (in Menu / Project structure / Modules ) but I also had to do the following:

1. Still in Project Structure goto Global libraries.
2. Select Scala SDK.
3. Right click the Scala SDK and Add to module...

Now my context menu gives me New / Scala class and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Once you've created a project and sbt has finished initializing, try creating another project. It should show up correctly in the new project, as it worked for me. It seems to be some kind of caching issue though Invalidate Caches/Restart didn't help me. Also, ensure that source directories are marked properly (source folders appear in blue color, test sources are in green).

Comment: Invalidating caches and restarting didn't work for me, creating another project did.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem everytime I created a new project with spaces in the name. eg "Hell Wev". Using "HellWev" as a project name seems to work fine

Answer (score 0):

Same issue (and solution) as @cwadeevans.

A project named "Week 1" did not show Scala files in the context menu "New". The solution was to delete the project and create a new one named "Week1".